# Как сделать, чтобы background-image не умножал изображения?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы background-image не умножал изображения?

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: Изучить основы CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-image:url(/img/top.png); само изображение 
background-repeat: repeat-x; (умножить)
background-repeat: no-repeat; оставить как есть
```

Выбирай сам какой вариант тебе больше подходит

Answer (score 3):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```